# Ruby 2.3.1p112 SyntaxError for keyword_rescue when using begin

Tags: ruby, rescue

I'm writing a program to validate CSV files in Ruby but I seem to not be using rescue correctly. I made sure to include the begin keyword. I'm using ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26) [x86_64-linux-gnu]

The code is here:

```
def self.validate
    begin
      CSV.foreach(@@filepath, headers: true) do |row|
    rescue CSV::MalformedCSVError
      return row
    end
    return -1
end
```

It's probably something silly, but I'm not sure what as I have the begin keyword included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need one `end` for the `do` block, one for `rescue` and one for `self.validate`.

If you use a text editor which can indent your code, it's easy to see the problem :

```
def self.validate
  begin
    CSV.foreach(@@filepath, headers: true) do |row|
    rescue CSV::MalformedCSVError
      return row
    end
    return -1
  end
```

If your editor cannot do it, find a better one! ;)

Comment: That was it. Thanks! I'll accept your answer when the time limit expires.